# Ящерица и тритон завизжали(,) как один

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Ящерица и тритон завизжали(,) как один.

Comment: зачем тут запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно записать так:

(1) *Все ящерицы и тритОн, / **как одИн,** / завизжАли.*

(2) *Все ящерицы и тритон завизжали **как одИн**, что и привлекло наше внимАние.*

**Пояснение**

1. Существует **[фразеологизм](https://phraseology.academic.ru/7792/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD_%28%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%29):** <ВСЕ> КАК ОДИН (ОДНА). Экспрес. Все без исключения.
2. Здесь желательно **наличие группы,** тогда использование сочетания будет правомерным, при этом местоимение "все" можно **опустить.**
3. Тогда обособление зависит **от позиции** сочетания, как и для всех **сравнительных оборотов.** Оборот обычно не обособляется **в конце фразы** (обстоятельственное значение), а в в другой позиции он имеет значения уподобления/сравнения и обособляется.

**[Пример решения](https://posostavu.ru/53315-ppodskazhite-nuzhno-li-obosoblyat-slovosochetanie-kak-odin-vsya-17861.html)**

Подскажите, нужно ли обособлять словосочетание "как один"? *Вся рота(,) **как один**(,) открывает огонь. Все(,) **как один**(,) опустились на колени.*

Лучший ответ: Если все как один употребляется в значении "все вместе", запятая не требуется. Но в первом примере нужна запятая: *Вся рота, **как один**, открывает огонь.*